# jQuery tmpl {{if}} condition with false not working

Tags: jquery, json, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I am using this in part of my template:

```html
{{if !IsDefault}}
    <a href="#" onclick="makeDefault('${Id}');return false;">Make Default</a>
{{/if}}
```

Except when `IsDefault` is false it is not working. I even tried:

```html
{{if IsDefault === false}}` and `{{if IsDefault == false}}
```

I have verified that the value actually is false in my json object that gets passed to the template.

I also tried this which works but is pretty ugly and I would prefer for it to just work how it should:

```html
{{if IsDefault}}
{{else}}
    <a href="#" onclick="makeDefault('${Id}');return false;">Make Default</a>
{{/if}}
```

Also, if I change it to check for a true condition (doesn't make sense but just tried it for debugging purposes)...

```html
{{if IsDefault}}
```

...it works fine. Looks like it just has problems with the false values. I am getting the json via an jQuery ajax call and using knockout mapping with jquery tmpl. I get no js errors.

Any ideas on why testing for `false` or `!false` is not working?

Comment: also tried {{if IsDefault === true}} which surprisingly doesn't work but {{if IsDefault}} does...

Comment: What does your JSON object look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `{{if !(IsDefault())}}`

If you are using an observable that is not in an expression, then jQuery templates sees that it is a function and calls it as a function to get the observable's value.  If it is in an expression, then this doesn't happen and you need to call your observable as a function (with no args) to get its value.

Answer (score 1):

For a Jquery Template like this:

```
{{if !IsDefault}}
    html_code
{{/if}}
```

The code is interpreted as this:

```
if ((typeof(!IsDefault) !== 'undefined' && (!IsDefault) != null) && (typeof(!IsDefault) === 'function' ? (!IsDefault).call($item) : (!IsDefault))) 
{
    __.push(html_code);
}
```

and because of this `typeof(!IsDefault)`, and the variable `IsDefault` doesn't exist, you will see ***Uncaught ReferenceError: IsDefault is not defined***

I don't know how to solve this, but for the meantime, this works for me:

```
{{if IsDefault}}
{{else}}
    html_code
{{/if}}
```